# Filter classes that are annotated with a specifi annotation

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm using Java Agents to manipulate bytecode and I would like to generate methods into classes that are annotated with a specific annotation. How can I do?

Something like this:

```
@Foo public class Bar {
    // inject methods here
}
```

If it is possible, filter by full qualified annotation name, like `com.example.Foo` instead of `Foo.class`.

Comment: Use Guava Reflections API https://farenda.com/java/java-find-annotated-classes/

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable solution using `ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith` method and passing annotation class as parameter, but I'm still looking for a way to filter by the full qualified annotation name as pure `String`.

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(isAnnotatedWith(ToString.class))
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                @Override public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(
                        DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
                        TypeDescription typeDescription,
                        ClassLoader classLoader,
                        JavaModule javaModule
                ) {
                    // do some logic here
                }
            }).installOn(instrumentation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ElementMatchers` to implement `hasAnnotation(annotationType(named(...)))`.